# bash script for create child process for ssh

Tags: bash

i want remote log for several hosts and check some configuration. for that i wrote a small script. it have two files. one for ip address list and other for script.

```
cat iplist
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
```

My script:

```
cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
while read ip;
 do
    sshpass -p 'root' ssh  root@$ip "hostname"
    echo "$ip" 
done < iplist
```

above script only display one hostname and one IP only

Answer (score 1):

ssh reads in from stdin and consumes all of your input file `ip_list` when its run the first time. You can use `-n` option to ssh command line to instruct it to not so.

Other ways are to use a different file descriptor for reading from `ip_list` or redirect input with `... </dev/null`.

Comment: i didn't get it. could you please explain

Comment: You pass `-n` option such as `ssh -n root@$ip "hostname"`. Otherwise, ssh would read in standard input (in your case, you are passing input from a file, so it'd read in the whole file in one go). See the man page and read `-n`'s description: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html